# How are consecutive days calculated?

Tags: support

Is it done by checking the server time, if so, which, or is it reset each time my "last seen" gets over 24h? Or a combination of those?

Comment: Ok, my ~70 consecutive days have been reset, I'm royally pissed off right now.

Comment: ["the user did not visit an interior page during UTC time"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129278), comment from Jeff Attwood. This is the most official answer I've found. I've found before, that just *displaying* the front page doesn't set the "visited" counter, you do need to *do* something (click on a question, check your rep, etc) to register for the day.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange uses [Zulu Time](http://www.zulutime.net/) (see also, [wikipedia on UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). You need to appear online during consecutive Zulu days, between 00:00Z and 23:59Z.